# Error using pixi.js v7.x.x within create-react-app v5: webpack + @babel/plugin-transform-parameters error

Tags: webpack, babeljs, create-react-app, pixi.js

I'm trying to use pixi.js in my react app created using create-react-app, however, am getting a webpack/babel error on npm start.

Versions

```
create-react-app v5.0.1
pixi.js v7.0.4
```

Code

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { Application } from "pixi.js";

function MyComponent() {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // On first render create our application
    const app = new Application({
      width: 800,
      height: 600,
      backgroundColor: 0x5BBA6F,
    });

    // Add app to DOM
    ref.current.appendChild(app.view);
    // Start the PixiJS app
    app.start();

    return () => {
      // On unload completely destroy the application and all of it's children
      app.destroy(true, true);
    };
  }, []);
 
  return <div ref={ref} />;
}
```

I run `npm install`, all fine. I then run `npm start` and I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@pixi/core/lib/textures/resources/ImageBitmapResource.mjs
 
SyntaxError: ./node_modules/@pixi/core/lib/textures/resources/ImageBitmapResource.mjs: When using '@babel/plugin-transform-parameters', it's not possible to compile \`super()\` in an arrow function with default or rest parameters without compiling classes.
Please add '@babel/plugin-transform-classes' to your Babel configuration.
6 |   constructor(source, options) {
7 |     var \__super = (...args) =\> {
\\>  8 |       super(...args);
|       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
9 |     };
10 |     options = options || {};
11 |     if (typeof source === "string") {
.
.
.
webpack compiled with 1 error
```

I've tried installing the @babel/plugin-transform-classes to babel config following [these steps](https://dev.to/ansonh/simplest-way-to-install-babel-plugins-in-create-react-app-7i5). Error persists.

Down-grading to pixi.js version `6.5.8` resolves the error, just hoping to find a solution that allows me to use 7.x.x

Cheers!

Comment: @domis86 I don't see any issues for the "Please add '@babel/plugin-transform-classes' to your Babel configuration." prompt, do you have examples?

Comment: @validname can you try these suggestions? https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/29326#issuecomment-773914999